# Processing For loop sequence

Tags: processing, sequence, ellipse

I am attempting to draw several ellipses in sequence along the y and x axis of the canvas. The dots are drawn at randomised y positions.

I previously had the ellipses drawing at random heights sequentially along the x-axis. However, all ellipses along the y-axis were drawn at once.

```c
 for (int x = 0; x < xStep; x++) {
    int mh = int(map(noise(offset+(x*0.05)), 0, 1, 0, h));


    for (int y = mh; y > mh - 3; y--) {
      ellipse(x*diam, y*diam, diam, diam);
    }
  }
  xStep++;
  if (xStep > w) {
    xStep = 0;
    offset = random(1000);
  }
```

I then moved on to add another for loop to try sequence the ellipses along the y-axis as well as the x-axis. So visually each ellipse is drawn one after the other on the y-axis before the next column (x-axis) is drawn. However, using the code below what I get instead is the y and x-axis 'drawing' in sequence but at the same time so visually it does not look like one row completes before the next column is drawn.

```c
  //count rows and frames
  if (counter > 7) {
    counter = 0;
    rowCounter++;
  }

for (int j=0; j<7; j++) { //set values to match counter
        if (j == counter){

          for (int x = 0; x < xStep; x++) {
            int mh = int(map(noise(offset+(x*0.05)), 0, 1, 0, h));

            for (int y = mh; y > mh - 3; y--) {
              y=y-j;
              ellipse(x*diam, y*diam, diam, diam);

            }
          }
        }
      }
  xStep++;

  counter++;

  if (rowCounter > 7) {
    rowCounter = 0;
  }

  if (xStep > w) {
    xStep = 0;
    offset = random(1000);
  }
```

Or if I try using a conditional for the xStep I only get one row of ellipses drawn.

```c
  //count rows and frames
  if (counter > 7) {
    counter = 0;
    rowCounter++;
  }

  for (int j=0; j<7; j++) { //set values to match counter
    if ((j == counter) && (xStep != lastXstep)) {

      for (int x = 0; x < xStep; x++) {
        int mh = int(map(noise(offset+(x*0.05)), 0, 1, 0, h));

        for (int y = mh; y > mh - 3; y--) {
          y=y-j;
          ellipse(x*diam, y*diam, diam, diam);
          xStep=lastXstep;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  xStep++;

  counter++;

  if (rowCounter > 7) {
    rowCounter = 0;
  }

  if (xStep > w) {
    xStep = 0;
    offset = random(1000);
  }
```

Can anyone help point me in the direction of where I am going wrong with the for loop construction? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that every call to the `draw()` function draws a single frame. Processing is double-buffered, so the screen is not updated until the very end of the `draw()` function. That's why you're only seeing the end result instead of the in-between steps.

If you want to render the in-between steps, you're going to have to split it up into multiple frames. You'd do that by keeping track of the **state** of your program in a set of variables, changing those variables over time, and using those variables to draw each frame.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) is a tutorial on animation in Processing that describes the above approach in greater detail.